# Extracting information from a log file using a regex

Tags: regex

Working on the following problem: http://regexone.com/example/6?

I'm finding myself not able to capture the first parenthesis using of a regex. This is my regex so far: `at (\w+).(\w+)\.(\w+)`

This is a sample line my regex should process: `at widget.List.makeView(ListView.java:1727)`

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say "not able to capture first parenthesis."?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to have regex 'capture' the first parethesis. I expected to do `\(` in order to match the parentheses, but that did not work for me.

Comment: Could you put a sample line in the question? It depends on what elements you are putting into the server log.

Answer (score 1):

To capture everything between some parentheses, include the parenthesis:

`(\(.*?\))`.  This would place, for example, '(ListView.java:1727)' in capture group 1, which you could, depending on regex flavor, reference as `\1`.

So, `(\(.*?\))` will end up with '(ListView.java:1727)' accessible via \1.

If you want to match inside the parentheses, but not capture the parentheses themselves as part of the capture, you could do:  `\((.*?)\)`.  Now \1 would be 'ListView.java:1727'.

If you want to get individual things within the parentheses, you could do something like `\((.*?):(.*?)\)`.  That will make \1 be 'ListView.java' and \2 be '1727'.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you actually will learn anything, if I just give you a working regular expression, but here you go:

```
at [^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.([^\.]+)\((.+):(\d+)\)
```

Or a little bit simpler:

```
at \w+\.\w+\.(\w+)\((\w+\.\w+):(\d+)\)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
.*\..*\.(\w+)\((\w+\.\w+):(\d+)\)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make it a bit more generic, i.e.

```
/at ([\w.]+)\(([^:]+):(\d+))
```

The memory captures are:

1. The class
2. The file name
3. The line number

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but using this pattern lets you click continue:

```
([\w]+).([\w]+\.[\w]+):([\d]+)

(        //First group
[\w]     //Match a single character
+        //Between 1 and x times
)        //End of first group
.        //any character (\W works too, \( unfortunately not)
(        //2nd Capturing group ([\w]+\.[\w]+)
[\w]     //Match a single character
+        //Between 1 and x times
\.       //The literal . char
[\w]     //Match a single character
+        //Between 1 and x times
)        //end of 2nd group
:        // Match colon char
(        //Start of 3rd group
[\d]     //Match any digits
+        // one or more times
)        //End of third group
```

There may be cleaner options, but this is one way regexone.com accepts as an answer